# Как сделать цветной вывод текста в Visual C++, как в Turbo C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
void main() {
    textcolor(RED);
    printf("Красный\n");
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Для того, чтобы изменить цвет шрифта и/или фона, используйте `SetConsoleTextAttribute()`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    int text_color = 4; /* Красный цвет текста */
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), text_color);
    cout << " Go, Red!";                      
    return 0;
}
```

Неплохая статья по теме - [тут](http://www.adrianxw.dk/SoftwareSite/Consoles/Consoles4.html).

Answer (score 2):

Хеадер conio.h - нестандартный, в Visual Studio его нет.

Comment: после того как убрал conio.h ошибка осталась
ошибка такая идентификатор textcolor не определен

Comment: textcolor - не стандартный

Comment: textcolor и getch это функции из conio.h

Comment: хорошо а какая есть функция в visual c++ похожая на textcolor

Answer (score 0):

*facepalm*
эта библиотека-conio.h содержит в себе описание textcolor и когда ты убираешь conio.h ты убираешь описание textcolor

Answer (score 0):

"*Шурик! Это же не наш метод!*" (с) "Операция "Ы" и другие..."

У нас же С++ с выводом в `cout` :)

```
enum Color {
    BLACK             = 0,
    DARKBLUE          = FOREGROUND_BLUE,
    DARKGREEN         = FOREGROUND_GREEN,
    DARKCYAN          = FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
    DARKRED           = FOREGROUND_RED,
    DARKMAGENTA       = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
    DARKYELLOW        = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN,
    DARKGRAY          = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
    GRAY              = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY,
    BLUE              = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
    GREEN             = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_GREEN,
    CYAN              = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
    RED               = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_RED,
    MAGENTA           = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
    YELLOW            = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN,
    WHITE             = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Color& att)
{
    if (&os == &std::cout)
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), WORD(att));
    return os;
}
```

И все, теперь разноцветный вывод делается так же, как и обычный :)

```
cout << BLUE << "C" << GREEN << "O" << CYAN << "L" << RED << "O" << MAGENTA << "R\n" << GRAY;
```