# Ошибка цветного вывода в консоль

Tags: c++, cmd, windows-11, ansi

Я пытаюсь сделать цветной вывод в консоли и столкнулся с проблемой. При выводе цветных символов появились аномалии (они появляются в любом варианте вывода, причем такой же код на python работает нормально).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

stringstream ss;
string pixel(float r, float g, float b, string str = " "){
    ss.clear();
    ss << "\033[48;2;" << r << ";" << g <<";" << b <<"m"<< str <<"\033[0;0m";
    return ss.str();
}


int main(){
    cout << pixel(0, 0, 0) + pixel(0, 255, 0)<<endl;
}
```

Вывод этого кода (пробел с измененным задним фоном)(зеленый??, пробел??, зеленый):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так должно быть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Черный "пиксель", потом зеленый, без пробела.

Код на python:

```py
def rgbPrint(rgb):
    print(f"\033[48;2;{rgb[0]};{rgb[1]};{rgb[2]}m \033[0;0m", end = '')

rgbPrint([0, 0, 0])
rgbPrint([0, 255, 0])
```

OS: Windows 11

компилятор: g++ version 7.3.0

Консоль: стандартная, "cmd.exe" в терминале Windows 11

Инфу о том, как сделать RGB в консоли брал [отсюда](https://habr.com/ru/companies/macloud/articles/558316/)

Comment: А ANSI в 11-й работает?... Я бы посмотрел [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/38605/195342), мне это кажется более надежным...

Comment: Работает, я же на пайтон смог реализовать

Comment: Прочитайте про [mcve], и добавье такой в вопрос. Нужно что-то, что мы можем сами скомпилировать, без каких-то секретных хедеров.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я изменил вопрос

Comment: Ну, я ваш код на Pyton запустил на Windows 10, получил белым по черному `←[48;2;0;0;0m ←[0;0m←[48;2;0;255;0m ←[0;0m` и не более того...

Comment: @Harry Я использую 11-винду + В статье, которую я указал, написано, что RGB поддерживается не всеми стандартными консолями

Comment: Получается легкая несовместимость по версиям, нет? Непереносимость вашей программы...

Comment: @Harry разве я виноват что не у всех RGB поддерживается? Попробуйте PowerShell, или установить Microsoft Terminal(хотя не знаю на счет терминала)

Comment: Да мне как-то стандартных консольных функций хватает, которые везде работают, независимо от версии и натсроек :)

Comment: @Harry но ведь RGB то не поддерживается у вас, проблема именно в консоли

Comment: Знаете, как-то тонко раскрашивать консоль в сотни цветов — как по мне, извращение... "Що занадто, то не здраво" (с)

Comment: Я хочу сделать цветную игру

Comment: @Harry На счет извращений, до того как я открыл RGB я использовал конвертер из RGB в 8 стандартных цветов windows + градиент из символов для регулировки яркости

Comment: @Hanji "Я хочу сделать цветную игру" - используйте оконный интрефейс, а не извращайтесь с консолью

Comment: @insolor, я хочу в консоли, оконный интерфейс я уже использовал, консоль это интересный опыт

Comment: Для начала напишите, какую консоль используете. Код написан так, как будто подразумевается, что консоль поддерживает произвольные RGB цвета. Хотя нет никаких оснований полагать что она вообще должна поддерживать хоть какие-то escape последовательности VT100 и тп.

Comment: @user7860670 Добавил информацию

Comment: *консоль это интересный опыт* — да уж, ностальгически вспомнаются времена BBS'ок, когда через ANSI-последовательности целые цветные мультики-заставки рисовали... :) Часто на тех модемах у особо навороченных BBS просто конца не удавалось дождаться :)

Comment: @Harry - `запустил на Windows 10, получил белым по черному` - в ссылку на хабр заглядывал? Там написано: `В начале программы надо сделать системный вызов, активирующий отрисовку цветов.` - Проще всего это сделать, вызвав из питон-скрипта cmd.exe (можно, например, выполнить пустую команду, см. [пример](https://gist.github.com/e-skri/cf6a5800f79aea4c31756dc0cf3657f9) на Lua)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147213/discussion-on-question-by-hanji-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: @ESkri Какой именно вызов? Покажите код на питоне для Windows 10, который будет выводить в цвете. Только без привлечения сторонних библиотек :) Просто чтоб не было потом, что я сделал не тот вызов какой-то...

Comment: @Harry - вставь в начало `os.system('')`

Comment: @ESkri А `import os`? :) Ничего не изменилось. Видеозапись показывать, или на слово поверите?

Comment: @Harry - Мне что, и про import os нужно было подсказывать? ))))  Я верил, что ты способен сам до этого догадаться ))) Щас проверю сам.  Надо только как-то питон на винду поставить...

Comment: @Harry - Всё работает!  Win10Pro 21H2, Python 3.11.1

Comment: @ESkri Мог и догадаться. Но я просил "Покажите код на питоне для Windows 10, который будет выводить в цвете." Полный код. А так вы можете меня обвинить, что я не тот импорт прописал. Win10Pro 22H2, Python 3.9.13. https://i122.fastpic.org/big/2023/0715/68/4a16885c2edf16a2470d31e72c0e2c68.jpg

Если вы скажете "ищи сам, что у тебя не так" — мне оно не нужно, это пусть беспокоится тот, у кого программа работает только на его компьютере, но не на других :)

Кстати, версия питона в полной мере ни при чем, ansi должен работать (если поддерживается) при любом выводе в консоль, откуда угодно.

Comment: @Harry - Попробуй на чистой винде, чтобы не было твоих кустарных настроек.  А то в принципе эти ANSI-коды можно и в реестре отключить. )))  Так что я скажу "ищи сам, что у тебя не так".  Потому что программа работает на любом компьютере с дефолтными настройками консоли, и писать программу конкретно для твоего частного нестандартного случая никто не будет.

Comment: @ESkri Я уже говорил, что мне это не надо :) Работать через ansi в консольном приложении — не через какой-нибудь терминал — это ж примерно из серии в консоли экран чистить через `system("cls")`... ТВОИХ (ну раз уж ТЫ хамишь, придется и мне) знаний для этого вопроса просто не хватает, вот ТЫ и пытаешься свое незнание на других свернуть :) P.S. Неужели и в самом деле не в курсе? Вопрос риторический, ответа не требует. https://i122.fastpic.org/big/2023/0716/b6/b529f157938c94ff52078553d7190eb6.jpg Цена только велика, некоторые программы при этом не работают.

Comment: @Harry - Обращение на "ты" - это не хамство, а общепринятый стиль общения в большинстве коллективов. ))) Любопытно, в чём была у тебя проблема с ANSI, как ты её пофиксил? И для справки: я консоль очищаю через Esc-последовательность, есть специальная короткая (2-байтная) для этого.

Comment: @ESkri У меня нет проблемы с ANSI. Сочувствую, если пришлось работать в таких коллективах, это плохо влияет не только на мораль...

Comment: @Harry - Ты писал `Ну, я ваш код на Pyton запустил на Windows 10, получил белым по черному` - я об этой проблеме.  Её удалось решить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы хотел отметить три момента:

Использование глобальной переменной `stringstream ss;` - видимо чтобы переиспользовать эту переменную в начале делается вызов `ss.clear();`, однако это не `::std::sting` и этот метод не подчищает ранее записанное содержимое, вместо этого он сбрасывает флаги состояния потока, так как это метод, унаследованный от `std::basic_ios`. Для удаления ранее записанного содержимого придется делать `ss.str(::std::string{})`, а лучше - просто сделать `ss` локальной переменной.

При вызове `pixel(0, 0, 0) + pixel(0, 255, 0)` записывается три символа, причем символ, оставшийся в `ss` при первом вызове, будет записан дважды. При этом в С++ еще и не определен порядок вызова этих функций, так что код может выдавать как зеленый - черный - зеленый, так и черный - черный - зеленый.

Консоль cmd.exe, хотя и обрабатывает расширенные цветовые директивы, однако вместо указанного цвета [будет отображать ближайший из палитры 256 цветов](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences?redirectedfrom=MSDN#extended-colors). Если это нужно, то имеет смысл попробовать [windows terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/install).

Comment: Вот почему я всегда говорю, что на С++ писать не стоит.

Comment: @avp - А что, в каком-то другом языке определён порядок вызова функций в выражении `f()+g()`?  Вроде бы это везде unspecified behivior

Comment: @ESkri в Java например порядок всегда строго определен *"The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated."* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7

Comment: @user7860670 - и порядок в скобках тоже? `f1(f2(),f3())`  обычно это оставляют на усмотрение компилятора, чтобы иметь простор для оптимизации

Comment: @ESkri И порядок в скобках тоже, там по ссылке дальше это разбирается.

Comment: Ну что сказать?  джава повёрнута передом к программисту, в отличие от.

Comment: @ESkri, в другом языке (том, что не ломает мозг) подобное выражение просто бы не возникло, оно бы ушло в строку *формата*

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `ss.clear()` используй `ss = {}` или `ss.str("")`

Метод `clear()` сбрасывает ошибку, вроде. Но это не точно.

Вот так работает, как надо:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

stringstream ss;

string pixel(float r, float g, float b, string str = " ") {
    
    ss.str("");

    ss << "\033[48;2;" << r << ";" << g << ";" << b << "m" << str << "\033[0;0m";

    return ss.str();
}


int main() {
    cout << pixel(0, 0, 0) + pixel(0, 255, 0) << endl;
}
```